# Rsync: pure Ruby implementation?

Tags: ruby, rsync

I have a Rsync program [Deltacopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) with an executable as client and server but would like to replace this if possible with a pure Ruby implementation of Rsync. I found gems like six-rsync and rsync-update but they seem to be no general implementations. I'm looking for a pure Ruby solution, so no executables involved and preferably runnable on multiple OS.
If possible a simple sample would be great.

I only look for [Rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), no other transfer or backup solutions please.

Comment: While I generally don't like such questions, this is well-specified, has an objective answer ("yes" - which, or "no"), and shows prior research, so no close from me ..

Comment: I think this would do better if asked on http://superuser.com/. Stack Overflow is for programming specific questions, which this question is not.

Comment: Hi Tinman, i look for a programming solution, Ruby in specific, it would a superuse question if i asked for a Rsync solution as an executible all in one program, i don't underzstand why you vote to close

Answer (score 1):

There's this:

- "Cheapest Rsync Replacement (with Ruby)"

  - Archived dzone: https://web.archive.org/web/20090101014459/http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1812
  - Archived original: https://web.archive.org/web/20070615023341/http://eigenclass.org/hiki.rb?cheap+rsync
- https://github.com/avh4/ruby-sync

  - "A full file synchronisation library for ruby, supports syncing/mirroring with local and FTP/SSH directories."
- http://synchzor.com/

Best of luck, sir.

Comment: thanks v-v but i really have done my own googling and had seen these before i made my question. None is a Rsync solution but rather simple imitations and just synchronising solution. Rsync is not just synchronisation, it's about synchronising only changed data on a bit level

Comment: Fair enough - the answers are for everyone, of course. I assumed you'd probably found them - but one never knows.

Comment: @peter it seems like you have tried the above solutions. I am only looking to sync one direction, based on file size and mtime. Did the above solutions meet that criteria?

Comment: i still use deltacopy cause i didn't find a pure Ruby Rsync solution, one-way or bidirectional, if Rsync isn't a requerement for you there are solutions here for you, but I didn't try them, for syncing PST files I made my own solution in Ruby only

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but it looks like rrsync might be a worth a try.

https://github.com/RichGuk/rrsync

Comment: as far as i can see this is only OSX and Linux, not Windows and relies on a functioning Rsync, so surelynot a pure Ruby solution.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll leave the answer just in case it's useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using Ruby Inline ( http://rubygems.org/gems/RubyInline and http://www.zenspider.com/ZSS/Products/RubyInline/ ).  You might be able to use the Rsync source code with Ruby Inline.

I don't know how this would work on Windows platforms, however.

---

Rsync source code: http://rsync.samba.org/download.html

Comment: i don't have the C sourcecode for Rsync and if i did it would be a lot of work to get this working  but i'm allways ready to try so i did install teh gem but even with inline required the base example on the website gives error "undefined method `inline' for main:Object (NoMethodError)"

Comment: Can you get the ImageScience gem to install or load?  I have only used Ruby Inline for ImageScience. This might help debug your issue getting Ruby Inline working.  It should also provide some sample code for how to utilize Ruby Inline.

Comment: when i gem install image_science and run a sample i get a screen full of errors, alseo from inline but that doesn't surprise me, on the website they only talk about osx and linux and the FreeImage i downloaded like they stipulated has no windows executable nor a wrapper for ruby

Comment: also the Rsync link you refer to is also only osx and linux , you need cwRsync which needs cygwin to run, highly improbable all this is gonna work with Ruby inline